# How to pass multidimensional array with events to Codeigniter calendar library?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Iam building a calendar and I have run into problem. I need to pass multidimensional array with events to the Calendar library

This is from Codeingiter's user manual:

```
$this->load->library('calendar');

$data = array(
               3  => 'http://example.com/news/article/2006/03/',
               7  => 'http://example.com/news/article/2006/07/',
               13 => 'http://example.com/news/article/2006/13/',
               26 => 'http://example.com/news/article/2006/26/'
             );

echo $this->calendar->generate(2006, 6, $data);
```

Is it possible to pass multidimensional array, something like:

```
$this->load->library('calendar');

$data = array(
               3  => array('url'=>'article/2006/03/', 'title'=>'Hello1'),
               7  => array('url'=>'article/2006/07/', 'title'=>'Hello2'),
               13 => array('url'=>'article/2006/13/', 'title'=>'Hello3'),
               26 => array('url'=>'article/2006/26/', 'title'=>'Hello4')
             );

echo $this->calendar->generate(2006, 6, $data);
```

and then somehow reference it in the calendar template, something like:

```
{cal_cell_content}<h1>{title}</h1><a href="{url}">{day}</a>{/cal_cell_content}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is extend the native CodeIgniter Calendar library, and overwrite the `generate()` function. In the while loop that buids the main body of the calendar, change the code that's build the cell content. Make it replace {title} with your given title, and {url} with your url.

I think changing:

```
$out .= str_replace('{day}', $day, str_replace('{content}', $data[$day], $temp));
```

With

```
$out .= str_replace('{day}', $day, str_replace('{title}', $data[$day]['title'],
str_replace('{url}', $data[$day]['url'], $temp)));
```

Will pretty much do it, but I haven't got the time to test it.

Comment: Hey cool, I just discovered it myself - and it works!! The only thing is I dont know how to properly extend Calendar class and override the generate function. I created MY_Calendar in application/libraries folder and extended CI_Calendar class - but that did'nt seem to work...

Comment: Create a MY_Calendar.php file in application/libraries/. And than `class MY_Calendar extends CI_Calendar{ // new generate function }`